# Using --env-file with docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

Im reading https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with---env-file and trying to "reproduce":

.env.docker1:

```
API_PORT=5001
```

.env.docker2:

```
API_PORT=5002
```

composer.yml:

```
volumes:
  app-data:

services:
  api:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: gunicorn ... 'main:app()'
    env_file:
      - .env.docker1
    ports:
      - "$API_PORT:5000"
```

When I run

- `docker compose up`, i've got API_PORT == 5001, it's ok
- `docker compose --env-file .env.docker2 up`, i've got API_PORT == 5001, it's wrong (i want 5002)

If i'll remove `env_file` section from composer.yml and then run

`docker compose --env-file .env.docker2 up`, i've got API_PORT is undefined, it's wrong too (i want 5002 again).

What I've understood wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to remove the `env_file` section from the compose:

composer.yml:

```yaml
volumes:
  app-data:

services:
  api:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: gunicorn ... 'main:app()'
    ports:
      - "${API_PORT}:5000"
```

Because:

> "With this option, environment variables declared in the file cannot
> then be referenced again separately in the Compose file or used to
> configure Compose."

.env.docker1:

```
API_PORT=5001
```

.env.docker2:

```
API_PORT=5002
```

You can test the resulting compose with the commands:

```bash
$>docker compose --env-file .env.docker1 config

$>docker compose --env-file .env.docker2 config
```

If you need kind of default behavior without specifying an environment file in the command line, create a file named `.env` in the same docker compose file directory. and docker compose will pick it up automatically.

.env:

```
API_PORT=5000
```

You can test the results with this command:

```bash
$>docker compose config
```

Comment: You are extremely right, my friend, thank you for your response. 

But it looks like `env_file` section has the "mapping" functionality: wihout it API_PORT var is not available from app. But if I append `environment` section with `API_PORT=$API_PORT` it starts to work fine.

Anyway thank you again and have a nice holidays!